# How do I get Eclipse to find the "org.eclipse.team.cvs.ssh" bundle?

Tags: eclipse, repository, m2eclipse, amazon-iam

I've been trying to install IAM or m2eclipse without success. Both of them need the org.eclipse.team.cvs.ssh bundle, but Eclipse Helios complains that the repository could not be found. I've been attempting to then just install that single bundle without success.

I select the "Helios - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios" repository and search for "cvs". This returns the "Eclipse CVS Client". I then attempt to install it. Eclipse says that it is already installed so it's just going to update the list of installed software. When I click finish, I am presented with the following error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:(profile=epp.package.rcp, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.cvs.ssh,3.2.100.I20090508-2000
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that this problem has been fixed in Eclipse. I just installed the Eclipse CVS Client without any issues.

Comment: Weird - I just downloaded "Ecplise RCP 64bit", and it works there!

Answer (score 2):

Found a resolution [here](http://dentrassi.de/2011/02/04/eclipse-install-issue/) that worked for me.

> While installing new software, deactivating the option `Contact all update sites during install to find required software` helps.

And it did.